# Accessing a variable from one file in another

Tags: python

I have a two-file setup:

> **File 1**:

```
global test
test = 1
import FooBar

FooBar()
```

> **File 2 (FoorBar.py):**

```
class FooBar:
    def Foo:
       print test
```

Essentially, I want to pass the variable `test` from File 1 to File 2. With the above code I get the exception:

> NameError: global name not defined (Python)

Comment: Read a python tutorial

Comment: Have you considered, you know, actually *passing* the variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try a different approach:

**File 1**

```
from FooBar import FooBar
FooBar.test = 1

foo_bar = FooBar()
foo_bar.Foo()
```

**File 2**

```
class FooBar:
    test = None

    def Foo( self ):
        print self.test
```

or

**File 1**

```
from FooBar import FooBar
foo_bar = FooBar( 1 )
foo_bar.Foo()
```

**File 2**

```
class FooBar:
    def __init__( self, test ):
        self.test = test

    def Foo( self ):
        print self.test
```

The difference is that in the first case the "test" variable would be static, i.e. the same for all instances of FooBar, in the second case it would be local to an instance (so different for all instances).

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. I guess one problem with the second approach is that one has to keep writing `self.test` inside `FooBar` instead of simply `test`.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work that way. You can merge names from one module into the namespace of another module, e.g. `from mymodule import *`. But you want to export names from your module into a different module. Whilst you could do that in a hacky way, it's not really how you are intended to program.

Instead, simply pass the value as a parameter to the `FooBar` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a host of problems here:

1. Foo looks like it is a method, but needs ()
2. If file 1 is meant to create a FooBar, then wouldn't you either need to save it to a variable (so you can DO something with it) or create an **init** method in FooBar to do something when FooBar is created?
3. File 1 doesn't need to declare test a global, but the method in File 2 certainly does

Answer (score -2):

You need a **global test** statement in both files for them to use the same global.